# Passing datetime object with GET method in django error

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to pass a DateTime object from object with a GET method. 
I keep getting the following exception:

```
time data '20/05/2016 11:00' does not match format 'd/m/Y H:i'
```

this happens in the view  when I'm trying to convert back from string to datetime with :

```
date = datetime.strptime(object, "d/m/Y H:i").date()
```

I've also tried :

```
date = datetime.strptime(object, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i").date()
```

and it sais: `'i' is a bad directive in format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'`

so when i remove the `%` from `i` it sais `time data '20/05/2016 12:00' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:i'`

Is there anyway to fix it or does anyone knows a good way to pass DateTime fields between 2 pages?

Comment: try `date = datetime.strptime(object, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%I").date()
` and notice the capital `I`. Also have a look at http://strftime.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: datetime.strptime('20/05/2016 11:00', "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").date()

Comment: Glad I could help!